# How to perform math operations between tidy data rows?

Tags: r, tidyr

I want to compare two results, one from year 2018 versus another from year 2017, for let's say two schools.

On a spreadsheet, i would have a column for `result2017` and another one for `result2018`, and i would do something like `result2018-result2017` on a new column and get the comparison i need for each row.

But in tidy data, or at least what i think is tidy data, i have no clue.

Most of the tutorials i have found are about how to use gather or spread, but not about what to do when you already got to create tidy data (which this may not yet be).

Minimal reproducible example:

```
dd <- tibble(
  school=c("A","A","B","B"),
  year=c("2017","2018","2017","2018"),
  result=c(20,40,25,45)
)
```

Comment: Your reproducible example should also show the exact desired output for the input. But in the dplyr world, you're probably going to want to use a `group_by` with `lead()` and `lag()` functions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and for editing my question. It was my first ever question so it was too verbose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `spread` after `paste`ing the 'result' string in 'year' column, then do the difference

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
dd %>% 
    mutate(year = str_c('result', year)) %>% 
    spread(year, result) %>%
    mutate(comparison = result2018 - result2017)
```

---

If the intention is to create a column in the original dataset

```
dd %>% 
   group_by(school) %>% 
   mutate(comparison = result[year == 2018] - result[year == 2017])
```

Comment: Thanks! I still have to grasp how to use tidy data. Most of the tutorials focus on how to tidy your data, but not on using it after tidying up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it. It creates a column, difference.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dd <- tibble(
  school=c("A","A","B","B"),
  year=c("2017","2018","2017","2018"),
  result=c(20,40,25,45)
 )

new_dd <- dd %>%
  spread(year,result) %>%
  mutate(difference = `2018`-`2017`)
```

Comment: Thanks!. I chose akrun answer because of completeness and reply time.

Answer (score 0):

Using data.table gives a row per school, and column per year and difference:

```
library(data.table)

dd <- data.table(
  school=c("A","A","B","B"),
  year=c("2017","2018","2017","2018"),
  result=c(20,40,25,45)
) 

# dcast to spread the year
dd <- dcast(dd, school ~ year)
# get the difference
dd[, diff := `2018` - `2017`]
```